# find command with multiple pattern not returning any output

Tags: shell-script, find, quoting

```
#!/bin/bash
pat="'*.ab' -o -name '*.bc'"
open="\("
close="\)"
path=path

find $path -type f $open -name $pat $close
```

Above code doesn't show any output for find. Do help

Comment: What is `path=path` supposed to do?

Comment: You don't need to escape `(` inside quotes.

Comment: @scai path is the location where the files are present

Comment: [Our reference question on quoting](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131766/why-does-my-shell-script-choke-on-whitespace-or-other-special-characters) explains the problem with `$pat`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
pat="'*.ab' -o -name '*.bc'"
find $path -type f $open -name $pat $close
```

This doesn't do what you want: the quotes within the variable `pat` aren't taken as quotes, but as literal characters. After `$pat` is expanded, it's wordsplit, resulting in the words `'*.ab'`, `-o`, `-name` and `'*.bc'`, with the single quotes still intact. So unless you have filenames with single quotes within them, this will not match.

```
path=path
```

This sets the variable `path` to the literal string `path`, but I suppose this was just a placeholder.

```
open="\("
close="\)"
```

These put literal backslashes in the variables, and `find` should probably complain as it gets an argument of `\(`. It's enough to quote the parenthesis once, so either `open="("` or `open=\(`

If you need to build a list of expressions for `find`, use a shell with arrays (Bash or almost anything but plain `sh`):

```
args=()  
args+=( -name "*.ab" )
args+=( -or -name "*.bc" ) 

find ... \( "${args[@]}" \)
```

Wrap the array-building in a loop as necessary.

Answer (score 2):

You're using the wrong type of variable, and forgetting to quote them.

Here, you need an array to store more than one argument:

```
#! /bin/bash -
pat=('*.ab' -o -name '*.bc')
open='('
close=')'
path=path

find "$path" -type f "$open" -name "${pat[@]}" "$close"
```

Note that it's a `*.ab` and `(` argument you want to pass to `find`, not `'*.ab'` or `\(`. Those quotes and backslash are part of the shell syntax.

That's only if you wanted to build a shell command line, for instance to pass to `eval` for the shell to evaluate it that you would do:

```
#! /bin/bash -
pat="'*.ab' -o -name '*.bc'"
open="\("
close="\)"
path=path

eval 'find "$path" -type f '"$open -name $pat $close"
```

For the shell to then evaluate:

```
find "$path" -type f \( -name '*.ab' -o -name '*.bc \)
```

Which as above results in `find` being called with these arguments:

- `find`
- `path` (content of `$path`)
- `-type`
- `f`
- `(`
- `*.ab`
- `-o`
- `-name`
- `*.bc`
- `)`

Comment: `eval find "$path" \( $expression \)` works.  That is, you need to `eval` the string.

Comment: That would be wrong and dangerous in the general case as `$expression` is not quoted and the *expansion* of `$path` (as opposed to a literal `"$path"` string) would be passed to `eval` (making it a command injection vulnerability for arbitrary values of `$path`). Note how I'm careful to pass `"$path"` inside single quotes and `$pat` inside double quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Use straightforward approach (instead of playing with variables):

```
find $path -type f -name "*.ab" -o \( -name "*.bc" \)
```

Comment: Pattern and path both will be arguments to the script .Hence making them dynamic